# Bigquery : Unexpected. Please try again when loading a 53GB CSV/ 1.4GB gZIP

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to load 1.4Gb gZIP data in to my BigQuery table and i am getting the error Unexpected. Please try again consistently

job_7f1aa8d29ae641459c82243530eb1c65

I was trying to load a structure Row ID,Order Priority,Discount,Unit Price,Shipping Cost,Customer ID,Customer Name,Ship Mode,Product Category,Product Sub-Category,Product Base Margin,Region,State or Province,City,Postal Code,Order Date,Ship Date,Profit,Quantity ordered new,Sales,Order ID

the error is not clear on whats going wrong.

anyone else encountered this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific? For instance, describe the structure of your CSV, which schema have you defined, an example of your data, etc.

Comment: You should update your question with those information, not put it in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your job ran out of time-- a 53 GB CSV file is a lot to process in one thread. Best practice is to either split your data in multiple chunks, or upload uncompressed data which can be processed in parallel.

I'm in the process of raising the allowed time somewhat, and we'll work on improving the error message when this happens.